# External reference to a relative pathname starting with "dot-dot"

Tags: hyperlink, python-sphinx, relative-path, restructuredtext

My Sphinx project needs links to a "sister project" whose home directory has the same parent directory as my project. Thus, the relative link from my project's index.html to a page in the sister project would look something like `../sister/subdirectory/somefile.html`.

In Sphinx I define an external target and use it in a link:

```
.. _syster: ../sister/subdirectory/somefile.html:

This is a reference to `some file in the sister project <syster>`__.
```

But instead of creating a tag like `<a href="../sister/subdirectory/somefile.html">`, it generates `<a href="subdirectory/somefile.html">`. It ignores the start of the URL until it gets down to the same level as my project's home directory, and then proceeds as if the rest of the URL were supposed to be *in* my project's home directory.

Is this normal behavior? Is there a way around it? It seems like an arbitrary limitation with no purpose except to make it impossible to do what I need to do.

Comment: Cross reference to another site should use other approaches, such as https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/cross-referencing-with-sphinx.html#cross-referencing-targets-in-other-documentation-sites Don't use your imagination and expect it to work as you wished.

Comment: I found several reasons why Intersphinx wouldn't work before I stopped reading. The simplest one is that "label names must be unique throughout the entire documentation." I can *absolutely guarantee* that label names aren't unique, because the "sister documents" are all versions of the same document for different releases of the same software.

I realized that I can compose the links with the :html: role, which works just fine. These documents will never be needed in a form other than HTML, so portability is not an issue. It's disappointing that Sphinx has this arbitrary limitation, though.